# What can cause SIGHUP to be generated?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel

We have about 40 computers running identical hardware and software. They all run Ubuntu 11.10.  They all have just one user account to log in. The .profile file is set up to launch a daemon process. The code for the daemon is written in C.

Once in a few weeks, we get a report that the daemon is no longer running. This does not happen on all computers but just one or two. We cannot reproduce the problem consistently.

Looking at the code, the application quits when it receives either SIGHUP or SIGTERM.

As I understand, SIGHUP is generated when a user logs off. In our case, the user never logs off. I am wondering if it is possible that SIGHUP could have been generated for some other reason. Any other thought would be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried logging to the daemon to see which of the 2 signals if any are causing it? SIGHUP seems to be triggered if the controlling terminal is closed, but if you are using server builds and just the 1 main term connection, i guess the difference is moot

Comment: Signals can also be sent manually. Who knows?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Signals can be sent using `kill` utility or kill syscall.
Of course, you can try and find out who is sending that signal or disconnecting your terminals or network connections, but there is simpler practical way to fix your problem.

When code is supposed to run as a daemon, but really isn't (just like yours), there is a wrapper that can turn any program into daemon. Surprise - this wrapper is called `daemon`! It has lots of options, probably most importantly for you, option to automatically restart your utility should it ever die for any reason.

If this command is not installed on your Ubuntu, just `sudo apt-get install daemon`, and `man daemon` to get started.

Comment: and there is also the `daemon(3)` library function.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The code is written to run as daemon (using fork, setsid, etc). However, I will looked at the external daemon tool as well.

Answer (score 30):

Well, there are a couple of things to note about SIGHUP. Firstly, its origin is from the concept of a hang-up, i.e. loss of connection to a console over something like a modem. In modern parlance this generally means it has lost its controlling tty. Unless you've taken care to detach from your tty, any program started in a given terminal will receive a SIGHUP when the terminal is closed. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777602/why-must-detach-from-tty-when-writing-a-linux-daemon) for details on how to do this in your program. Other options include:

- running your program inside `screen` or `tmux`
- run your program with `nohup` or some other daemonising framework

The other possibility is something is deliberately sending your process a SIGHUP which by "tradition" is often used to signal a process that it should re-read its configuration.