# Why daemon needs to fork off the parent before detaching from a control terminal?

Tags: linux, background, terminal, daemon

Why does a `daemon` in `linux` needs to fork off the `parent process`  and then get detached from controlling terminal ?

Comment: [Why MUST detach from tty when writing a linux daemon?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8777602/why-must-detach-from-tty-when-writing-a-linux-daemon?)

Comment: _@Thanks kaylum_ for providing the link